# Permissions & Scripts

Tags: raspbian, ssh, permissions, root

I am trying to run camera.sh which I made executable by

```
chmod 755 camera.sh
```

It works okay, but when I run it I get the error...

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/timelapse# ./camera.sh
-bash: ./camera.sh: Permission denied
```

I even logged in as root, but I still got the same error.
I can't even run chown/chmod/owner commands to 777.
It pretty much gives me a permission error for everything I do.

Permissions on file shown below:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/timelapse# ls -l camera.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 234 Jul 29 10:02 camera.sh
```

I am running Raspbian and SSHing from my desktop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is timelapse.sh a typo for camera.sh?  What does ls -l camera.sh report?

Comment: @joan Yeh, it's a typo, timelapse.sh should be camera.sh. But that is the command I am running (Now edited the question)

Comment: show us the output of `ls -l camera.sh`

Comment: @askmish `root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/timelapse# ls -l camera.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 234 Jul 29 10:02 camera.sh
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/timelapse#`

Comment: goto your non-root login. Then, try this `chmod +x camera.sh`. Do not prefix the command with sudo. Then try running it.

Comment: If that doesn't work try this: `chmod 0755 camera.sh`. Post the results.

Comment: @askmish For both commands I get: 
`chmod: changing permissions of 'camera.sh': Operation not permitted`

Comment: you should then change the ownership of the directory and file like this `sudo chown <your username>:root /your/directory/where/the/script/is/in` and then `sudo chown <your username>:root camera.sh`

Comment: @askmish On both my non-root and root account I get the error message `chown: changing ownership of '/home/pi/timelapse': Permission denied`

Comment: @askmish Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16036/discussion-between-user3686883-and-askmish).

Comment: What is in the shell script? Probably some non existent directory or file referenced there

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be a wrong `fstab` entry and a corrupted OS. See the comments and discussion in chat, between the OP and me, to troubleshoot such issues, in future.

Comment: if you answered your own question (or it got answered in the comments in this case), please select it as the answer when you can.

Comment: @Askmish, can you go into the chat please